# DAX Power BI Conditional filtering

Tags: powerbi, dax

[Sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KUJMpp5d95dDcR8m9LlnLBOvlU3-NH1b/view?usp=sharing)

The column `c` of a table `T` can have the values `1, 2 or 3`. I want to filter the table such as when the user selects value `1` nothing is filtered. When the selected value is `2` then show only the rows with the `c` column containing the value `2` or the value `3` not the value `1` and finally if the selected value is `3` then show only those rows containing `3` in the `c` column. The slider or a plain filter must be single selection not multi because otherwise it would violate one of the user's business rule.

```
Selected    Show
    1     all rows
    2     rows with 2 or 3
    3     only rows with 3
```

I tried to create columns and to create measures but I can't get anywhere. Any directions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree that the disconnected table might be the best workaround here. I hope this solution will work with your actual file.

**Step 1** - create a new disconnected table

```
FilterC = DISTINCT(T[c])
```

[image]

**Step 2** - make sure that your slicer is sourced from the new table (FilterC)

[image]

**Step 3** - create a measure that will return 1 for rows that we want to see, and 0 for rows that we want to hide:

```
mFilter = 
    var Filter_C = SELECTEDVALUE(FilterC[c])
    var Row_C = SELECTEDVALUE(T[c])
return
    SWITCH(
        Filter_C,
        "1", 1,
        "2", IF(OR(Row_C = "2", Row_C = "3"), 1, 0),
        "3", IF(Row_C = "3", 1, 0)
    )
```

**Step 4** - add this measure to the table, or even table filters will suffice.

[image]

**Step 5** - start switching the values!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Just what I need

Answer (score 1):

First you need to set it to a number column.

[image]

Second, you could write complex measures and use a [disconnected table](https://www.blue-granite.com/blog/disconnected-table-power-bi), but the best option is to use the correct slicer. There is a `Greater than or Equal To` option.

[image]

Comment: That column is indeed text. The real values are words. Could you elaborate on the measures?